# Action isn't call functions on view, from template - Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js

SO basically I create a view like so (I create it like this as I need it to act as a pop up)

```
    Application.container = Ember.ContainerView.create();
    Application.container.append();

    Application.loginOverlay = Application.LoginOverlayView.create({
    });
    Application.childViews = Application.container.get('childViews');
    Application.childViews.pushObject(Application.loginOverlay);
```

I have a view that looks like this

```
Application.LoginOverlayView = Ember.View.extend({
templateName: 'view/loginOverlay',
password: null,
logBackIn: function (password) {
    console.log('logBackIn');
},
closeOverlay: function () {
    console.log('closeOverlay');
},
username: function () {
    return Application.user.get('username');
}.property().volatile()
});
```

Here's my template

```
<div id="login-overlay" class="overlay">
    <section>
      <form id="login_form">
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="username">{{localise _username}}: {{username}}</label>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="reenter-password">{{localise _password}}</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    {{view Ember.TextField name="reenter-password" elementId="reenter-password" valueBinding="password" placeholder="password" type="password"}}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <input type="button" value="{{localise _login}}" class="btn btn-success" {{action 'logBackIn' password target="view"}} {{bindAttr disabled=busy}} />
                <input type="button" value="{{localise _cancel}}" class="btn btn-danger" {{action 'closeOverlay' target="view"}} {{bindAttr disabled=busy}} />
            </div>
        </form>
    </section>
</div>
```

The actions on the view are doing anything when clicked.

I'm using an old verion of Ember - v1.0.0-rc.7-9-g7398406

Any ideas?

****EDIT****

I did try it with the actions hash like so

```
Application.LoginOverlayView = Ember.View.extend({
    // layoutName: 'view/loginOverlay',
    templateName: 'view/loginOverlay',
    password: null,
    init: function () {
        console.log('LoginOverlayView');
        this._super();
    },
    actions: {
        logBackIn: function (password) {
            console.log('logBackIn');
        },
        closeOverlay: function () {
            console.log('closeOverlay');
            Application.removePasswordOverlay();
        },
        username: function () {
            console.log('username');
            return Application.user.get('username');
        }.property().volatile()
    }
});
```

but no joy. Also I added the init to make sure it was being created and it was, the log is being called

Another thing to add is that I'm not getting any feedback when I click the buttons. I'm not getting any kind of error or anything.

Comment: Try adding your action handler methods inside an actions hash - see http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html#property_actions

Comment: I tried that, thanks. I updated my question